# ggplot2 Reorder Data that is in minutes:seconds Format

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, geom-col

The first five entries (out of twenty) of my dataset:

```
>head(data)

 Name         SDC 
 <chr>        <Period>
1 Feuerman    1M 37S
2 Solis       1M 52S
3 Osborne     1M 47S
4 Frizzell    1M 58S
5 Moran       1M 59S
```

Also:

```
> dput(head(data))
structure(list(Name = c("Feuerman", "Solis", "Osborne", "Frizzell", 
"Moran", "Seth"), Deadlift = c(320, 250, 340, 250, 250, 200), 
Medicine_Ball = c(11.6, 8.8, 12.5, 9.2, 9.7, 9.1), HRP = c(46, 
39, 36, 33, 42, 31), SDC = new("Period", .Data = c(37, 52, 
47, 58, 59, 15), year = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), minute = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)), Leg_Tuck = c(20, 
13, 4, 10, 13, 13), Run = new("Period", .Data = c(48, 59, 
10, 53, 0, 29), year = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), minute = c(13, 12, 17, 16, 0, 16)), Total = c(570, 
508, 513, 470, 410, 452), Pass_Fail = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Pass", "Fail"), class = "factor"), 
Date = structure(c(18522, 18522, 18522, 18522, 18522, 18522
), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As you can see, `SDC` is in `minutes:seconds` format. I achieved this using `ms(data$SDC)` to change the column type. I am trying to create a plot using `geom_col` that orders `SDC` from lowest to highest times. I am facing two problems:

1. When using the `reorder` command, the times are not properly reordered (see plot below).
2. The axes are being formatted by `hour:minute:second` but I want it to be formatted in only `minute:second` format (also see plot below).

Here is my code to generate the plot:

```
ggplot(data=data,
   aes(x=reorder(Name, -SDC), y=SDC, fill=Pass_Fail)) +
  scale_y_time(limits=c(0,200)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#00BFC4', '#F8766D')) +
  labs(x='Soldier', y='Sprint Drag Carry Time', fill='Passed/Failed ACFT', title='Sprint Drag Carry Scores') +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(size=3, aes(label = SDC), hjust=-0.04) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
```

It produces the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, the reordering is incorrect and the axes are not formatted the way I want them to be. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think `reorder` have trouble working with `Period` object. We can arrange the factor levels according to the value of `SDC` to get bars in increasing orders.
2. We can pass custom function for y-axis to get only minutes and seconds in labels.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  arrange(SDC) %>%
  mutate(Name = factor(Name, levels = unique(Name))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=Name, y=SDC, fill=Pass_Fail) +
  scale_y_time(limits=c(0,200), 
               labels = function(x) sprintf('%02s:%02s', minute(x),second(x))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#00BFC4', '#F8766D')) +
  labs(x='Soldier', y='Sprint Drag Carry Time', 
      fill='Passed/Failed ACFT', title='Sprint Drag Carry Scores') +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(size=3, aes(label = SDC), hjust=-0.04) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]